# How can we generate PDF/A or PDF from html (contains SVGs) using iText7?

Tags: java, itext7

I tried to generate PDF using HTMLConverter.convertToPDF(inputStream, outputStream) but looks like generated PDF doesn't render SVG elements. In my team, we are exploring option to use or not iText for this or align with some other libraries. Our main aim to store archived data in PDF/PDF-A format.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of iText? 7.1.3, to be released this week, features (partial) SVG support. 7.1.2 also had SVG support but much less complete.

Comment: i am using 7.1.2 'kernel', 'io', 'layout', 'forms', 'pdfa', 'bardcodes' , 'hyph'  and  2.0.2 'html2pdf'. Actually, we use D3 generated SVGs (graph data) into html but it seems to be not rendered. Also, tried with simple blob '<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>'  but it not rendering

Comment: Also, we would like to know, will itext 7 future version will fully support SVGs into HTML ? Because, it depends on our technology decision to use or not iText library for PDF generation. Again, Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I cannot answer that question on Stack Overflow. Contact iText Software directly if you want to know more about SVG.

Comment: Sure will do that.